# get the registrations of a user in conferences that didnt finished

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code to get registration of a users in conferences that have the status incomplete (I).

```
    $IncRegistrations = $user->registrations()->where('status', 'I')->count();
```

But do you know how to get the registrations of a user in conferences that have the status incomplete but only for the conferences that have the column 'end_date' smaller than now(), that is, conferences that did not finish already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `whereDate`

```
$IncRegistrations = $user->registrations()
    ->where('status', 'I')->whereDate('end_date', '<', Carbon::now())->count();
```

**EDIT** After Comments use `whereHas`

```
$IncRegistrations = $user->registrations()
    ->where('status', 'I')
    ->whereHas('conference', function($query){
          $query->whereDate('end_date', '<', Carbon::now());
      })->count();
```

Comment: Thanks, but like that shows "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'end_date' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `registrations` where `registrations`.`user_that_did_registration` = 1 and `registrations`.`user_that_did_registration` is not null and `status` = I and date(`end_date`) < 2018-08-11 16:10:53)". The end_date column is from conferences table not registrations table.

Comment: what is the relation between `registrations` and `conference` ?

Comment: Registration model "public function conference(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
    }".

Comment: Conference model "
    public function registrations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Registration', 'conference_id');
    }
".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
$IncRegistrations = $user->registrations()->where('status', 'I')
->where(DB::RAW('DATE(end_date)'), '<', DB::RAW('DATE(NOW())'))->count();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it appear ""SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'end_date' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `registrations` where `registrations`.`user_that_did_registration` = 1 and `registrations`.`user_that_did_registration` is not null and `status` = I and DATE(end_date) < DATE(NOW())) ◀"
".